# Delete colum of index 0 of dataframe pandas with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datatable

I hope you can help me to sovle my problem, I am trying to do a programm where I can print out a pdf with a table that have 3 variable po#,name and description, when I used panda and I introduce PO# and convert this to html and then pdf, this happens[It shows everything but it has a row that contain a 0 with it and I can not dele this with drop(), how can I do to delete this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xd7Lf.png)

It shows everything but it has a row that contain a 0 with it and I can not dele this with drop(), how can I do to delete this?

this is my code
[THIS IS THE CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJgRa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the CSV file, it's tricky to estimate from where the zero may come from. However, from the pandas [official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), the `loc` accepts the labels of the rows and only accept:

- single labels (and accesses the whole raw);
- a range of rows;
- boolean array or Series (all `True` indexes will be selected);
- a callable function that returns one of these;
- **a list of labels**.

That means the `loc[]` method doesn't accept the grid position of the cell listed with commas but instead a label to the column. In your case, when you type `file.loc[0, "P)#"]`, Pandas treat `0` as a label of a row. Remember that `loc[]` treats all values as labels and never as indexes, therefore what I suggest you to do instead is to select the "PO#" row and assign its first item to the desired value:

```py
file.loc["PO#"][0] = po_number
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about the head of the columns. You can rename the column headings. If you want to hide the column the use [hide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide.html).

To rename column there are different methods one option is a list.

```
df.columns = [["column name"]]
```

To hide the column head I recommend that you read the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide.html) but it would be something like...

```
df.style.hide(axis="columns")
```

Place the DataFrame on the clipboard with out the header, try this...

```
df.to_clipboard(header=False)
```